# How to use local storage in my TODO list js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a task in javascript, I'm learning but don't now how to use the local storage, or how to use it in my todo list, I can add task, mark them and delete, but when I refresh the browser the task vanishes, I've been trying for days an do not find the answer haha. This is my js code:

```
//informacion de las fechas 

const dateNumber = document.getElementById("dateNumber");

const dateText = document.getElementById("dateText");

const dateMonth = document.getElementById("dateMonth");

const dateYear = document.getElementById("dateYear");

const placeDate = () => {

    const date = new Date();

    dateNumber.textContent = date.toLocaleString('es', { day: 'numeric' });

    dateText.textContent = date.toLocaleString('es', { weekday: 'long' });

    dateMonth.textContent = date.toLocaleString('es', { month: 'short' });

    dateYear.textContent = date.toLocaleString('es', { year: 'numeric' });

};
placeDate();

//div contenedor de las tareas

const taskListContainer = document.getElementById("taskListContainer");

const setDate = () => {

    return moment().format('MMMM,  Do,  YYYY');
};
setDate();

const addNewTask = event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const value  = document.getElementById("taskText").value;

    if (!value) {

        alert ("Debes escribir algo para que se agregue la tarea!!!");

        return};
  
    task.classList.add ("task", "roundborder");

    task.addEventListener("click", changeTaskState)

    task.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){

    taskListContainer.removeChild(task)

    })

    task.textContent = value;

    taskListContainer.prepend(task);

    event.target.reset();

};


const changeTaskState = event => {

    event.target.classList.toggle('marked');
}

const order = () => {

    const marked = [];

    const toDo  = [];

    taskListContainer.childNodes.forEach( element => {

        element.classList.contains('marked') ? marked.push(element) : toDo.push (element)

    })

    return [...toDo, ...marked];
}

//funcion para que al darle al boton de ordenar, se marquen como realizadas
//iteramos cada elemento de los arrays en order y lo agregamos a la lista de tareas del taskListContainer

const orderedTasks = () => {

    order().forEach(element => taskListContainer.appendChild(element))
}
```

and my HTML:

```
    <h1 >Lista de tareas</h1>
    <form onsubmit="addNewTask(event)" >
        <input type="text" id="taskText" autocomplete="off" placeholder=" " class="roundBorder">
        <button type="submit" class="add-button">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="orderButton roundBorder" onclick="orderedTasks()">Ordenar</button>
     </form>
    <h4><small> 1 click = marcar, 2 click = eliminar</small> </h4>
    <div id="taskListContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I'm only seeing a `localStorage.getItem('id')` in the code you pasted, where is the part where you set the item in the local storage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So I notice you never even set anything to the local storage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

I'd recommend this docs to find on how to interact with the localstorage api.

Or this guide: https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/

So like in add new task you say getItem from local Storage but you never set the Item to the local storage.

Comment: Thanks, I did some changes in the code, and now is working correctly, it tooks me a good amount of time to solve it, but, finally made it /o/